# Selenium: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document in Python

Tags: python, selenium, dom

I'm using Python's version of Selenium to iterate through Select elements options. It works quite well on of the websites, but fails on the another one, with error: `Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document` I looked it up of course, but the answers I found didn't work out for me. I use `time.sleep()` to wait for page to load and I can see it being loaded in the browser. I'm not sure what should I do with it.

How it looks in code:

```
options = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("my_element's_xpath")).options
for option in options:
    option.click()
    sleep(5)
```

First run it works fine, second run I get the error.

Here is the Select element in Dev Tools in Chromium:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uX7g7.png)
I believe it might have to do something with first select option not having `<option>` tag around it, but I'm not sure how to remove it from DOM.

Comment: Are you sure selection an item does not cause page to reload? In that case, the DOM element stored in `options`  variable will no longer be available. Yes, there (probably) will be identical element on the new page, but it would be a different element.

Comment: Oh, so I checked the network and yes, it does reload the page. Is there a way around it? edit: I believe storing option names in one way then applying this names to new set of options maybe?

Comment: Yes, what you need to do is to refresh `Select(...)` at each iteration. Than the list of options will be valid.

Comment: Can you share webpage URL if it's public

Comment: It's unfortunately not, I can't. The code here was simplified though, I was clicking other button and it triggered refresh. I have idea how to solve it though, hoping to implement it tomorrow. I will defiently share it here. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in my program is a bit larger than what I showed, and as J0HN pointed out, it caused browser to refresh. I solved it in a kind of hack, storing each option value in references list, then iterating through it. Code speaks better than words so take a look at it below:

```
for option in options:
    options_reference.append(option.text)

for option in options_reference:
    option_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            "//*[contains(text(), '" + option + "')]")
    option_element.click()
```

It can be further improved by narrowing down XPath to option tag only.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was enough to add `sleep(2)` (taken from `from time import sleep`) before `options = Select(...)`